# Write CSV to String using opencsv without creating an actual file or a temp file

Tags: java, file, opencsv

I'm trying to use the opencsv library to write a csv file. The restriction being that I do not want to create a file on the disk or even a temp file. Is there a way I can achieve it?

From what I looked, the constructor for CSVWriter requires a FileWriter object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Actually the [constructor](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter.html#CSVWriter%28java.io.Writer%29) needs a [`Writer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) and you could provide [a `StringWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) to create a String.

Answer (score 11):

To modify the example given [here](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#can-I-write), just use a [StringWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) instead of a FileWriter:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String[] rowData = {"column1", "column2", "column3"};

    try (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(sw)) {
        csvWriter.writeNext(rowData);

        String csv = sw.toString();
        System.out.println("CSV result: \n" + csv);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `CSVWriter` takes a `Writer` instance, so you can simply pass a `StringWriter`. After the write operation, you can ask the `StringWriter` for it's content using `toString()`.